# connection refused in R

Tags: r, connection, port80

I'm using multiMiR package to for miRNA target retrieval. Till yesterday this package was running fine and now it is showing following error:

```
library(multiMiR)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘multiMiR’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'multiMiR', details:
  call: function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) 
  error: Failed to connect to multimir.org port 80: Connection refused
```

I tried to reinstall multiMiR package and restart rstudio. but still, it is showing the same error.
I don't understand how to solve this connection problem.

The below link I checked but I don't understand if that's the problem with my query here.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/676434/port-80-connection-refused

Any help will be appreciated.
please find below session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7             lattice_0.20-44        corpcor_1.6.9          png_0.1-7             
 [5] Biostrings_2.60.1      snow_0.4-3             assertthat_0.2.1       digest_0.6.27         
 [9] foreach_1.5.1          utf8_1.2.1             RSpectra_0.16-0        R6_2.5.0              
[13] GenomeInfoDb_1.28.1    stats4_4.1.0           RSQLite_2.2.7          httr_1.4.2            
[17] ggplot2_3.3.5          pillar_1.6.1           zlibbioc_1.38.0        rlang_0.4.11          
[21] rstudioapi_0.13        blob_1.2.1             S4Vectors_0.30.0       Matrix_1.3-4          
[25] DT_0.18                reticulate_1.20        Rtsne_0.15             htmlwidgets_1.5.3     
[29] RCurl_1.98-1.3         bit_4.0.4              munsell_0.5.0          umap_0.2.7.0          
[33] compiler_4.1.0         pkgconfig_2.0.3        askpass_1.1            BiocGenerics_0.38.0   
[37] htmltools_0.5.1.1      doSNOW_1.0.19          openssl_1.4.4          tidyselect_1.1.1      
[41] KEGGREST_1.32.0        GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.6 tibble_3.1.2           matrixcalc_1.0-4      
[45] IRanges_2.26.0         codetools_0.2-18       XML_3.99-0.6           fansi_0.5.0           
[49] crayon_1.4.1           dplyr_1.0.7            bitops_1.0-7           grid_4.1.0            
[53] jsonlite_1.7.2         gtable_0.3.0           lifecycle_1.0.0        DBI_1.1.1             
[57] magrittr_2.0.1         scales_1.1.1           cachem_1.0.5           XVector_0.32.0        
[61] doParallel_1.0.16      ellipsis_0.3.2         generics_0.1.0         vctrs_0.3.8           
[65] iterators_1.0.13       tools_4.1.0            bit64_4.0.5            Biobase_2.52.0        
[69] glue_1.4.2             purrr_0.3.4            M3C_1.14.0             parallel_4.1.0        
[73] fastmap_1.1.0          AnnotationDbi_1.54.1   colorspace_2.0-2       BiocManager_1.30.16   
[77] cluster_2.1.2          memoise_2.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a (hopefully) temporary issue. The error does not seem to be on your side - at the time of writing the site multimir.org is [currently down](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/multimir.org?proto=http), which is why you are getting an error.

As the package depends on connection to external database, I encourage you to raise an [issue on their repository](https://github.com/KechrisLab/multiMiR/issues).

EDIT July 20th 2021: The site is now up.

Comment: Thank you very much mhovd. I have raised the issue on multiMiR repository.

Comment: The page is now up, and the error should be resolved. Can you check if you are able to load the package now?

Comment: Hi mhovd, yes i could load the package. thank you!!